# PS | Deleting Local User Profile | Get-WmiObject -Query Not working

Tags: powershell

I am literally 1 Line away from getting this PS Task completed. Would one of you mind taking a look? This script simply checks the users directory, checks each local users creation date, and deletes it using WMIObject. Everything works up to line 34 (Marked it with ===> in Code block). Error being thrown on my WMI Query. I cannot find out why... Working with WMIExplorer it looks correct.

```
$Admin = "Administrator"

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem C:\Users\)
{
    if ($file -in $Admin)

        {
            Write-Host = "`r`nUser account is" $file ". This is an Administrator Account, it will not be deleted."
        }

    else

        {

            Write-Host = "`r`nUser account is" $file ". Checking profiles age..."
            $FileDate = (Get-item C:\Users\$file).CreationTime
            Write-Host = $FileDate 
            $TestDate = (Get-Date).addDays(-30)
            Write-Host = $TestDate

        If ($FileDate -lt $TestDate)

            {
                Write-Host = "Since" $file "is older than 30 Days (" $FileDate ") it will be deleted."
                $UserAccountPath = "C:\Users\$file"
     ====>      $WMIQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE localpath = $UserAccountPath"
                $UserProfile = Get-WmiObject -Query $WMIQuery -ComputerName $Computer
                Remove-WmiObject -InputObject $UserProfile 

            }

        else

            {
                Write-Host = "Since File is dated less than 30 days old (" $FileDate ") it will not need to be deleted."
            }

        }

}
```

When it is run I get the following Error:

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE localpath = C:\Users\radconrm"
At C:\Users\AVC00\Documents\PowerShell\Profile Maintenance\TestCommands.ps1:18 char:13
+ $profile = (Get-WmiObject -Query $WMIQuery -ComputerName $Computer)
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Remove-WmiObject : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Users\AVC00\Documents\PowerShell\Profile Maintenance\TestCommands.ps1:19 char:31
+ Remove-WmiObject -InputObject $profile
+                               ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-WmiObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveWmiObject
```

I look forward to your insight! Thank you for your time in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double the backslashes.  Add quotes to what localpath is equal to.  It's like SQL.

```
$UserAccountPath = "C:\\Users\\$file"
$WMIQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE localpath = '$UserAccountPath'"
$UserProfile = Get-WmiObject -Query $WMIQuery -ComputerName $Computer
```

You may find something like this easier:

```
get-wmiobject win32_userprofile | where localpath -eq c:\users\$file
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea how much this has helped me out. I appricate your help and will make sure to watch my "\" and ' '!